# 'Class' does not name a type

Tags: c++, constructor, header

Board.h

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include "piece.h"


class Board
{
    public:
        Board(bool);
        //Piece * getPiece(int x, int y){return &pieceboard[x][y];}
};

#endif
```

Board.cpp

```
#include "Board.h"

Board::Board(bool fill)
{
...
};
```

Gives me the error: 'Board' does not name a type.
Compiled it with gcc.

EDIT:

Code compiled after i had commented out #include "piece.h". Apparently it had some undeclared classes in it.

```
#ifndef PIECE_H
#define PIECE_H

#include "Board.cpp"

class Piece{

    public:
        virtual bool checkMove(int, int) =0;
        bool movePiece(int, int);
        int getX(){return x;}
        int getY(){return y;}
        char getChar(){return image;}
        bool getWhite(){return isWhite;}

    protected:
        int x, y;
        char image;
        bool isWhite;
    };

    class Pawn : public Piece{
    public:
        Pawn(bool, int, int, Board); // ERROR: 'Board' has not been declared
        bool checkMove(int, int);
    private:
        Board * board; };            // ERROR: 'Board' does not name a type

#endif
```

Comment: What does `piece.h`contain? Show us the content. Seems like a case of circular `#includes`.

Comment: Does `piece.h` contain some references to `Board` or something else interesting? The fault can be there.

Comment: That semicolon `;` isn't required after the definition of the constructor `Board::Board`

Comment: Which line of which file is the error pointing to?

Comment: Why are you compiling a `.cpp` it with **GCC**?

Comment: Perhaps i can refer you to this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961103/error-does-not-name-a-type

Comment: the problem is that you're including `Board.cpp` instead of `Board.h` and you're including `piece.h` in `Board.h`. this is causing a recursive `include`

Comment: @TaylorFlores Still got the same error after changing it to `Board.h`

Comment: @Soup read my comment again. You're also including `piece.h` in `Board.h`. remove that. `piece.h` can't be including before the prototype in `Board.h` is defined.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Does that mean i should forward declare the classes instead of including them and then include the headers in my main file?

Comment: @Soup no. just change `#include "Board.cpp"` to `#include "Board.h"` and move `#include "piece.h"` out of `board.h` and into `board.cpp`

Answer (score -3):

The code is fine. I guess the error is due to something lurking in "piece.h"

Comment: This does not provide a solution to the problem and should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: But given that the problem lies in a piece of code that is not provided it is The nearest thing to an answer that could possibly be given.

Comment: He was right thou. The code compiled after i had commented out that inclusion.